# Copy data from Office 365 BasicDataSet_v0.Message_v0 into Azure using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, office365api, office365-apps

Problem: I am trying to load data from Office 365 by using Azure Data Factory. When I test connection of the linked service I am getting error:

> Office365 data loading failed to get OAuth token. Operation returned an invalid status code 'InternalServerError'

*Screenshot of the error:*

[image: ADF linked services - connection error]

Tried: I have created linked service (Data store - Office 365). By following steps from this link: [Microsoft - Getting started with Microsoft Graph Data Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/build-may-2021/microsoft-365-teams/breakouts/od483/)

I have registered Application via Azure AD-App Registration for generating Application (client) ID/Service principal ID and Client secrete/Service principle Key.

Two permission are there under API permission page in Application with Granted admin consent.
[image: API Permission]

Please help me I am unable to find the reason , I can't find the missing gear to drive.

Answer (score 1):

this is Guosen from ADF dev team.
Can you double check the service principal id and key? Making sure they are all correct.
[image: service principal id]

Comment: Yes, I am using Application ID as Service Principle Id.

Comment: @Amit Have you resolve the problem?

Comment: No, raised ticket to the Microsoft for the same. They are looking .